# Error in ListView on Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

please help me, i have error in onCreate like this

Multiple markers at this line

- The method setContentView(View) is undefined for the type FindPeopleFragment
- The constructor View(int) is undefined

second error in ListView, error like this

- rootView cannot be resolved

third error in Adapter, error like this

- The constructor SimpleAdapter(FindPeopleFragment, ArrayList>, int, String[], int[]) is 
  undefined

please help me, to resolved this

### FindPeopleFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment  {

    public FindPeopleFragment(){}
      protected ListView lv;
      protected ListAdapter adapter;
      SimpleAdapter Adapter;
      HashMap<String, String> map;
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
      String[] Pil;
      String[] Ltn;
      String[] Gbr;


      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new View(R.layout.activity_pulau));

        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);

        Pil = new String[] {"", "", "", "", ""};
        Ltn = new String[] {"", "", "", "", ""};
        Gbr = new String[] {Integer.toString(R.drawable.coba),
                                     };

        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Pil.length; i++){
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("list", Pil[i]);
            map.put("latin", Ltn[i]);
            map.put("gbr", Gbr[i]);
            mylist.add(map);             
        }

        Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.item_kepulauan,
                  new String[] {"list", "latin", "gbr"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_des, R.id.imV});
        lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pulau, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inflate a `View` in `onCreateView(...)` like

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pulau, container,
            false);
```

and `return rootView;` at the end on `onCreateView(...)`

### Corrected:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pulau, container,false);

    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);

    Pil = new String[] {"", "", "", "", ""};
    Ltn = new String[] {"", "", "", "", ""};
    Gbr = new String[] {Integer.toString(R.drawable.coba),
                                 };

    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Pil.length; i++){
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("list", Pil[i]);
        map.put("latin", Ltn[i]);
        map.put("gbr", Gbr[i]);
        mylist.add(map);             
    }

    Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, R.layout.item_kepulauan,
              new String[] {"list", "latin", "gbr"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_des, R.id.imV});
    lv.setAdapter(Adapter);

    return rootView;
  }
```

Comment: how about Adapter ?? @MD

Comment: listview can't show in fragment, why? ERROR LIKE THIS : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 and at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.FindPeopleFragment.onCreateView(FindPeopleFragment.java:48) @MD

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahP It's because your `Gbr` array has only one element. while your all other `Arrays` have 4 elements on it. So add 4 elements on Gbr array.

Comment: how to click in listview to change layout webview in fragment??

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahP If your this problem is solved then ask another question with another problem...